# How to make an environment such as "theorem" not have italics

Tags: environments, theorems

I found this:  [How to change the font style in theorem environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24666/how-to-change-the-font-style-in-theorem-environment) as well as this: [Italic in theorem environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8156/italic-in-theorem-environment) Neither however seem to make sense to me as I have been using the following:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{theorem} \emph{(Fundamental Lemma)} Let $A$ and $A'$ with collections $\partial$ and 
Stuff goes here: But it becomes "italicized"
\end{theorem}
```

However it seems that with the above two links one is either just defining whole new constructs (which I somewhat understand), or just using `\textbf`, which I don't want the `\textbf` to override the italics as I don't want bold faced text.  What I am after is being able to construct a "Theorem" which keeps track of the numbering and updates itself i.e. 1.1 to 1.2 if another theorem tag is added before.

Comment: You can use `\begin{theorem}[Fundamental Lemma]` instead of `\begin{theorem} \emph{(Fundamental Lemma)}`

Comment: A simple solution can be found with  the `ntheorem`, not mentioned in the answers to question 38260.

Comment: @Ruben -- thanks.  but the preferable way to get what i think is being asked is (using `amsthm`): `\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}[section] ... \begin{mytheorem}[\emph{Fundamental lemma}] theorem text \end{mytheorem}` which will put the theorem text in roman type, not italic.  (i'm not entirely clear about this; the question sends me a mixed message.)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ntheorem` package, this is really simple : write in  your preamble something like:

```
\usepackage[thmmarks,thref,hyperref,amsmath]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{numberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries\itshape}% Remove \bfseries if you only want the title in italic
\theorembodyfont{upshape\mdseries}
\theoremseparator{. ---} % Really old-style
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand*\thethm{\thesection.\arabic{thm}}
```

All the specifications above will remain valid for all subsequently declared theorem structures until changed.

The `thmmarks` option (not used here) is for the good placement of `end of theorem` (proof) symbols, especially if a proof ends in a displayed (group of) equation(s) — in most cases this is automatic with  `ntheorem`; `thref` is for cross-references and `amsmath`is necessary for the two previous options if you use amsmath.